# Can't get Tor browser wizard to work

Tags: windows, help

I have installed Tor but every time I try and open the browser nothing happens, just a blue circle for a couple of seconds. I am sure I should get a Tor browser wizard.

Have tried opening as administrator, still the same. Have deleted and reinstalled several times including the new test version.
I just don't get it the last time I installed Tor was on an old laptop worked fine straight from go. This laptop is now dead, hence the desktop need.

My system is Windows 10. And yes I did turn PC on and off again.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Potentially antivirus, it commonly is on Windows. First of all, ensure you're installing it to a directory you have permissions to, e.g. your Desktop folder and second of all if that doesnt help reboot windows into Safe Mode with Networking and try again.